# jquery ajax load partial view to div tag MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've been searching around with no luck on how to make a jquery call to load a partial view in a div tag on my Index view. Some how I am not getting the partial view to update when I click on a link on my tree. The partial view loads when I first run it b/c I call `<div id="divid">
@Html.Partial("_InnerView")</div>`. After that nothing happens when I click on the link. Or maybe I am not getting the full picture here. Some mentioned to use `$('#divid').load = data;` or `$('#divid').innerHTML= data;` but nothing works for me. This is what I have.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Test(string parentEls)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.Name = parentEls + "1";
            return PartialView("_InnerView", employee);
        }
        return View("_InnerView");            
    }
```

Index view:

```
<div id="divid">
@Html.Partial("_InnerView")</div>


$('#tree a').click(function () {
    var parentEls = $(this).parents('ul').map(function () {
        return $(this).find('a').first().text();
    }).get().join(", ");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Test")',
        data: {
            parentEls: parentEls                
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#divid').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
});
```

_InnerView.cshtml:

```
  @model TreeDemo.Models.Employee
```

EmpName:@Model.Name

UPDATE: I got this to work with this

```
 $.ajax({ url: '/Home/Test/', contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8', type: 'GET', dataType: 'html', data: { parentEls: parentEls } })
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use

```
$('#divid').html(data);
```

instead of

```
$('#divid').innerHTML = data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Load Partial View in a div MVC 4

Recently I want load Partal View in Div , after doing lots of R&D and It's     work for me

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")',
    data: {
        title: title
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#divid').innerHTML = result;
    }
});

    And In Partal View Action Controller Code

    public PartialViewResult ShowCategoryForm(string title)
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.Title = title;
        return PartialView("~/Views/ControllerName/PartalView.cshtml", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be useful if you check the request/response objects of your call, so you can see what is really happening after you make the call... As per your code, I can notice that you're posting using

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Test")',
        data: {
            parentEls: parentEls                
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#divid').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
```

but your action is marked for 'getting'... you'd need to have something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string parentEls)
```

so MVC can understand that the action should be called when HttpPost verb is used

Comment: In debug mode. When I click the link it does hit my action Test method. It just doesn't render the _InnverView in the div tag. Newbie question. How do I check the request/response objects of the call?

Comment: If you use Chrome, on Nework tab of developer tools you can see tab details. You can do the same in Firebug if you use Firefox... I think it is also posible to check it in IE, but not sure how

Comment: Ok. I did that and when I click on the link I see the Method=POST in Firefox>Network. When double clicked on it the POST it shows Status code: 200 OK. In the Respondse tab. I see the data that I clicked on: <div class="editor-label"> T: &#160;Texas, &#160;USA  </div>

Comment: Any ideas? Maybe it's not refreshing when I click a link? I see the div tag in my partial view (_InnerView) populated with data that I clicked on in Firebug but it's not showing up.. This is what I see <div class="editor-label"> T: &#160;Dallas, &#160;USA  </div>

Comment: try clearing the content of the div and then adding the results... I think I had a similar issue some time ago and that's how I solved it

Comment: That didn't work. I've added $('#divid').empty(); right before $('#divid').innerHTML = data;. The funny thing is that the div tag actually clears out, but it doesn't show the new partial view data.

Comment: Thank you for the help and being patient with a newbie like me. I got it. I use this: $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Test/',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                parentEls: parentEls
            }
        })