# Replicating web form in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to MVC, but I get the general concept.
However, I'm stuck trying to replicate a page that was very easy to create in web forms.

In web forms, I have a dropdownlist (Majors), that when selected, does a postback and displays a listbox (Courses) based on the value from the DDL.
  Then, when an item from the listbox is selected, another postback occurs and a grid (Classes) is displayed based on the item from the listbox.
 During the postbacks, the selected items in the DDL and Listbox stay selected.

In my attempt at this in MVC, I've got spaghetti code all over...

My question is, can I accomplish this, with one Controller, one View, and three Partial Views?  I just want to stick with plain MVC, I can work in the jQuery once I get it working.

Comment: the only way to maintain selection with a post back is to pass the selection to the controller and then pass it back to the view.  It can be painful.  I would recommend looking into ajax calls to load your partial.  here is one of many results of googling that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337665/jquery-ajax-load-partial-view-to-div-tag-mvc

Comment: so I guess there are times where something easy in webforms is more complex in MVC?

Comment: It's easy enough in MVC with minimal code and without jquery (although you will get far better performance using jquery). But you have not shown you code so how do you expect us to identify your problems

Answer (score 1):

You have to load up the Dropdowns and have model for real record on page so that there is alt least 3 models..... so you will have to use a Viewmodel to bring all 3 models together

So do up your model classes  for Classes\course\Main model (Student?) then create a viewmodel for all 3

Then your view has access to viewmodel and all classes/data