# Asp.net Core 3.1 - open the view with Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

There is no error but the view is not displayed?

Jquery :

```
  $('#edit_button').on("click", function () {
        var instance = $('#jstree').jstree("get_selected");
      
        if (instance != 0) {
            $.getJSON("/AdminPanel/Category/EditMainCategory/" + instance);
        } else {
            swal("choose category");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Controller :

```
 public IActionResult EditMainCategory(Guid Id)
    {
        var maincategory = _admin.GetCategoryById(Id);
        return View(maincategory);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to show the content of view. Then load the view in particular control you want. may be this link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337665/jquery-ajax-load-partial-view-to-div-tag-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
if(instance != 0)
{
 window.location.href = '/AdminPanel/Category/EditMainCategory' +instance
}
```

I assume that instance is your id parameter on EditMainCategory function